# Understanding the "like" in "like father, like son"

Tags: grammar

How do we understand the "like" in "like father, like son"? Is it an adjective? Or is it short for "is like"?

Comment: It's like a two-way simile.

Comment: It is a short and witty generalisation. It means, 'A son is always like his father and a father is always  like his son.'

Comment: Classically this is an *idiom*. It makes no grammatical sense but everyone accepts it and knows what it means.

Comment: @chasly: Surely the wittiness, if there ever was any, has long since worn off.

Answer (score 6):

Many proverbs and catch-phrases do not follow the normal rules of grammar.

Apart from this phrase, I cannot think of a context in which you could use *like son* without an article. (You could use *like Father*, but only if you are treating *Father* as a proper noun).

A normally grammatical form of this would be something like *What the father is like, the son is also like*: in that formulation you can see that *like* is a predicative adjective. I think that is also the case in the proverb, although I don't think it is possible to determine this syntactically.

Answer (score 2):

*Like father like son.*

***As*** the father is/was, **so** is/was the son.

Both 'as' and 'so' are adverbs expressing a comparison of equivalence.

This is a very familiar phrase whose power derives in no small part from the elliptical, ear-catching, idiomatic (though 'wrong') use of two '*likes*' rather than the more usual (and less punchy) *as... so...* .

*Like father like son*  is usually made as a comment (gossipy!) by people who know/knew both father and son, when the son does something that was a habit of his father's.

It covers all kinds of behaviour and activity.  The sense of it is usually to emphasise that we are products of our genes and/or how we were nurtured.

Comment: (Deleted my comment, which no longer applies since you edited the answer).

Answer (score -1):

'like' in this context means the father and son are alike, i.e. they are  very similar in their behaviour.

Comment: But this doesn't address the question; OP is asking about the grammar involved, not the semantics. Oh, and hello, Heather.

Answer (score -1):

Neal R. Norrick, in [How Proverbs Mean: Semantic Studies in English Proverbs
 Neal R. Norrick](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WtO1txl7DJwC&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=like+father,+like+son+grammar&source=bl&ots=0x-mNY3L5e&sig=VOASmeGCPEYKlCtMtYXgOfRrHJ8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBGoVChMItZLevOX5yAIVh1QUCh3n8AfS#v=onepage&q=like%20father%2C%20like%20son%20grammar&f=false), discusses this particular proverb. Although he is prepared to accept some 'extra-grammatical' idioms and proverbs etc as being deleted forms, he says that this is not really the best analysis here:

> This proverb does not count as radically elliptical, because one
>   cannot correctly paraphrase it by adding only semantically neutral
>   constituents to it. Thus neither
>
> *If it is like father, then it is like son*
>
> nor
>
> *That which is like father is like son*
>
> But rather
>
> *Son is like father*
>
> or
>
> *Father and son are alike*
>
> paraphrases this proverb.
>
> … One other item in the F-corpus has the same form:
>
> *Like fault, like punishment*
>
> But many further examples may be found in the ODEP [the Oxford Dictionary of English Proverbs], eg *Like master,
>   like man / Like priest, like people / Like cow, like calf….*
>
> If there are several such [proverbs having the same formula]
>   [(snowclones)], it seems natural to place them together in a separate
>   part of the regular grammar of English or in a distinct grammar
>   altogether. Quirk et al reserve a section of their monumental English
>   grammar for proverb formulas and similar utterance templates.

If an undeleted form is recoverable, one might feel justified in saying 'this word is a remnant of ...'.

But if traditional grammar is deemed inadequate to adequately describe these structures, the parts of speech of traditional grammar should not be expected to be sufficient either.